# How can I connect these bits of C# code to get the program to work properly?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a program where the user should be able to locate any folder and the program will return the files/folders (sub directories) within the path that was selected, as well as the date and size of each file/folder.

I used the folderBrowserDialog to allow the system to be searched, including networks (most every where else I was looking ONLY returned the C:\, but we have more than just this. The folderBrowserDialog allows this to happen. Earlier I thought I found some code that would help me futher with what I am trying to accomplish, but it turned out to be what I don't need, at least it was a learning experience, except for the recursion process.

I believe I have the code for the size of the files and directories as well as the date time. I found those [size](http://www.vcskicks.com/csharp_filesize.php) and [date](http://www.dotnetperls.com/filename-datetime).

At the moment when I build the code I am given two error messages

```
1. 'DD.Form1.GetFileSize(double)' not all code paths return a value. 

2. The name 'txtFile' does not exist in the current context
```

and only the first part of the code runs (with the folderBroweserDialog), the textbox isn't working and I would like for the user to enter the path and it search for the path and bring up the same data - Folder/File names and paths including subdirectories along with date and size of all. What do I need to do to get this working properly? Thank You

Here is my code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace DD
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void browse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //
            // This event handler was created by double-clicking the window in the designer.
            // It runs on the program's startup routine.
            //
            DialogResult result = folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                //
                // The user selected a folder and pressed the OK button.
                // We print the number of files found.
                //
                string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath);
                MessageBox.Show("Files found: " + files.Length.ToString(), "Message");
            }

            //Obtaining the sub directories in a folder
        }

        void DirSearch(string sDir)
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(sDir))
                {
                    foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(d, txtFile.Text))
                    {

                    }
                    DirSearch(d);
                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception excpt)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(excpt.Message);
            }
            {
                //Obtaining the date and time of a file
                // Write file containing the date with BIN extension
                //

                string n = string.Format("text-{0:yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss-tt}.bin",
        DateTime.Now);
                File.WriteAllText(n, "aaa");
            }
            //Obtaining the size of a file
        }
        private string GetFileSize(double byteCount)
        {
            string size = "0 Bytes";
            if (byteCount >= 1073741824.0)
                size = String.Format("{0:##.##}", byteCount / 1073741824.0) + " GB";
            else if (byteCount >= 1048576.0)
                //etc...     

                return size;

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This is a horrible question it hardly deserves an up vote.

Comment: You have ommitted important code to be able to answer part 1.  we need to see all of the GetFileSize(double) method.  Second, in your DirSearch method, the second foreach loop the assumption would be there is a winforms control with a Text property called txtFile on your form that contains a filter for the files you wish to search for.  The compiler seems to believe that control does not exist.

Comment: That was part of the code was from what I found earlier here - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303974. I don't want lstFiles....lstFilesFound.Items.Add(f); this is what I ommitted.

Comment: then what you are doing is only returning the size in the else if condition.  since you do not have {} in place to signify you want to do nothing, the else if takes the next executable line as its code block.  that means that the return only executes in the else if condition

Comment: @Comp - If you want help post any and all code you want help on.  At this point what you have posted is not complete, undeclared variables, and syntax problems.

Comment: @Ramhound- I am aware of the issues, that is what I am asking help with so I can better understand what is going on. I am NEW to C# and trying to learn it while I am building this project at the same time. You have all the code that I have.

Comment: @Comp - Most of these issues have nothing to do with being new to C# they are basic programming mistakes.  I for example see a nested foreach loop that does nothing.  You should remove that.

Comment: In addition File.WriteAllText(n, "aaa");  makes no sense.  The "aaa" is the text being written to the file.  the n variable would be the path and or filename.

Comment: @Ramhound - Oh the nested foreach is on the microsoft website that I found earlier that went over recursion found [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303974). Since it was on Microsoft website, I thought it was correct being in this format. Also there is the lstFilesFound.Items.Add(f); I have not declared this because I dont plan on using a lstFiles, again this is from something I did earlier and I am working on making modifications. If I want a recursion for all of my folders and sub directories to be displayed under the folder the user selects, don't I want to keep foreach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have taken a quick look at the article you referenced and here are some comments that may help out.

First lets take a look at

```
private string GetFileSize(double byteCount)         
{
             string size = "0 Bytes";
             if (byteCount >= 1073741824.0)
                 size = String.Format("{0:##.##}", byteCount / 1073741824.0) + " GB";
             else if (byteCount >= 1048576.0)
                 //etc...
             return size;
}
```

What this should look like is something more like this

```
private string GetFileSize(double byteCount)
{
        string size = "0 Bytes";
        if (byteCount > = 1073741824.0)
        {
           size = String.Format("{0:##.##}", byteCount / 1073741824.0) + " GB";
        }
        else if (byteCount >= 1048576.0)
        {
            //do something else in here
        }
        return size;
}
```

You do not have to use the braces in the if/else statement to deliniate your blocks of code to execute if it is only a single line, I have included here for clarity.  The C# compiler will associate the next executable line of code after and if or else  with that if or else unless you use the {} to indicate the block or end the if or else line itself with a ";"

The next problem you are having, is with the textFile.Text reference in the foreach loop.  This is most likely a Textbox control on the form in the example.  The parameter that you are filling in there is a filter for the type of files you are searching for.  So you most likely do not have a Textbox on your form that has the name textFile.

Edit:
There is no one line command to get a list of all files recursively in a directory structure built in to the .NET framework.  So you have the method below to do that for you.  The way you would use this to have a single list of all the paths would be as follows.

```
List<FileInfo> DirSearch(string sDir)
     {
         List<FileInfo> filesList = new List<FileInfo>();
         try
         {
             foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(sDir))
             {
                 foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(d, txtFile.Text))
                 {
                    fileList.Add(new FileInfo(f));
                  }
                 DirSearch(d);
             }
         }
         catch (System.Exception excpt)
         {
             Console.WriteLine(excpt.Message);
         }
         return fileList;
     }
```

Now you can print out the details of each of those files by something like this.

```
foreach (FileInfo fi in new DirSearch("c:\"))
{
     console.Writeline(String.Format("Filename: {0}   Size:  {1}", fi.Name, fi.Length));
}
```

Comment: OH I see, thank you and I also added the MB and KB sizes according to the chart on that site. `code` } else if (byteCount >= 1048576.0) { size = String.Format("{0:##.##}", byteCount / 1048576.0) + " MB"; } else if (byteCount >= 1024.0) { size = String.Format("{0:##.##}", byteCount / 1024.0) + " KB"; } return size; }`code`

Comment: @CompGeekess: looks much more correct to me now :)  Did you get the part about the textbox control?

Comment: Yes, I went to my textbox control and renamed it to txtField. That error went away :). However, there are still just two tiny issues. One when I run the code it only picks up the folderBroweserDialog. When I select a drive, it outputs how many files are in there and closes. The one last thing is where the recursion occurs: `code` foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(sDir)){ foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(d, txtFile.Text)){  `code` I have lstFilesFound.Items.Add(f); I honestly dont know what should go here as this is the recursion to get all files and folders, sub directories.

Comment: @CompGeekess:  The internal foreach loop is where you will do what you want to do with each individual file.  Right now you are doing nothing.  The  f string variable will contain the path to a file contained in the directory.  so you could for example write the path to the console with a line like console.Writeline(f);  and it will process each directory recursively.  (I suspect this is where you would get your file size but I am not really sure what your end goal is.

Comment: @Bueller- I want the program to generate a list (text file) of all the files from whatever path the user chooses (this includes network drives) - including all the sub directories below it. It needs to list the date of the file, the size and the file name with path.

Comment: @Bueller - I thought if I could use the folderBroweserDialog that would be a starting point since it does list not just the main drives, but also the network drives. Yes, I am aware that it counts how many files are in each folder and I am going to remove that as it's not relevant to this project.

Comment: @CompGeekess: have a look at the FileInfo class http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx  You can create a FileInfo object for each path you find then add that to whatever list you are using.  You can then get properties for each file from the FileInfo objects you have stored.  (You would create the objects and store them in the list from within your internal foreach loop something like   FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(f);  mylist.Add(fi);

Comment: @Bueller - Maybe I am not understanding correctly, do you mean I have to find every single path and create an object for each one individually? Or is there a way to capture all of the paths with a single/ or few lines of code?

Comment: @CompGeekess:  check the end of my answer, I have made some edits to show a possible method to accomplish what you want.  In short there is no single command built in to recursively get all files in a directory structure.  The DirSearch method you have will do that with a small modification.  Then you can do what you like with the list of files.  Of course you could simplify this and just add the string version of the path to the list rather than creating fileinfo objects but that is up to you how you want to do what your are doing.

Comment: I have to allow the user to choose any path in from any of the drives that we have and have what they chose out put the data.

Comment: You have the pieces you need to make this work.  You have to figure out now how to put them together to get what you want.  We are here to help not do for you so give it another try and if you have more questions please post another question with details.  I will let you know up front that most mentors here will not take kindly to general how do you write a program questions.

Comment: Right, I am not expecting anyone to do this for me, just help guide me. Thank you, I will keep that in mind.

Comment: Are these forums only for advanced users? If so, where can I go then?

Comment: @CompGeekess:  not only for advanced users but it is expected that users will try first, then ask specific questions about what they tried and how it can be made better.  I am not trying to be mean, but you will learn more from trying things out than getting code provided for you.  Unfortunately you seem to be under the gun to learn a new language while providing some actual code.  Makes things difficult.

Comment: some great tutorial sites exist for just about everything you need to do in C# and .NET and to a lesser extent VB.NET.  codeproject.com is one of my favorite, used to use CSharpCorner once upon a time but haven't been there in a while but there are many many many more.

Answer (score 0):

lstFilesFound isn't declared in the method using it and I can't see it in your code.
txtFile isn't declared in the method using it, and like the other variable, I don't see it in another scope in your code.
GetFileSize should include an else after the else if.  It's required because of your use of if/else if prior to it.

Comment: opps thats not supposed to be there...sorry, thats part of the recursion code I found earlier. Found here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303974

Answer (score 0):

The code in the following code block clearly does not return a value for the TRUE and FALSE statement.

In this context IF = TRUE else = FALSE of course I suggest using { and } on ALL IF statements until you have a general understanding of this fact.

```
    private string GetFileSize(double byteCount)     
    {           
  string size = "0 Bytes";            
 if (byteCount >= 1073741824.0)             
    size = String.Format("{0:##.##}", byteCount / 1073741824.0) + " GB";   
          else if (byteCount >= 1048576.0)   
              //etc...                       return size;   
       }
```

> The name 'txtFile' does not exist in
>   the current context

You never declared a variable called txtFile thus you cannot use it as a variable.  My guess your trying to use a textbox control's Text property.